# What will happen if I kill a huge MySQL InnoDb DELETE Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm currently running a `DELETE` query that is taking a lot longer than expected (already 10hrs!). I would like to kill it through phpmyadmin processes, however am concerned about what might happen. Will the roll-back he automatically does take a lot of time also? Current query status shows "updating".

Comment: It depends on the stage your query is in right now.

Comment: @favoretti It's in "updating" stage (according to processes status column)

Comment: I'd say 10 hours is a long time, but it seems now you're *committed* `</BadPun>`

Comment: He's not yet past the norollback stage, never, actually unless the logs will expire, but the rollback operation will be equally painful :)

Comment: @favoretti - So *Ze evil transaction gremlin* likes to make us suffer?  ;) (On a serious note, +1 big rollbacks can be painful).

Comment: +1 for "Will the roll-back automatically, does take a lot of time also?" - thoughts of a wise man i.e. think before you act. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the stage your query is in right now.
But generally rollback takes about equal time, sometimes even more than the original operation.

As per point 2 of [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/optimizing-innodb-transaction-management.html), it's not really advisable.

Also, be sure to verify your MySQL version as it has a VERY nasty bug with delete/update queries rollback in some versions as per [this article](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45309)

Restarting/killing the MySQL process won't help as rollback will resume upon restart.

Comment: I'm not worried about it not doing the rollback, but don't want it to take the same time to finish the query. Any recommendations? What will a restart do?

Comment: Can't I kill the rollback? Anything but waiting forever? It fells like something got stuck...

Comment: `strace` the process, see whether it got stuck or just crunching? How many rows are you deleting, how many rows does table have so that it's taking you this long?

Comment: The table had 600M rows and I'm deleting ~10M.

Comment: Right.. Well.. takes kinda ridiculously long, although that's of course subject to `delete` conditions, but I'm not sure there's a sane way to abort it without risking data corruption. Depending on your situation, killing, ditching the database and restoring from some other slave (if you have one) might be faster.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18545/discussion-between-noam-and-favoretti)

Comment: @favoretti The first link (Oracle) seems to be dead now, I get a 404 on it

Answer (score 2):

Thumb rule is:

> Just let it rollback by its own and don't even think about restarting
>   the DB as it will resume after restart but worse is your DB won't be
>   accessible meanwhile.

Yes rollback of huge data (i.e. millions of rows) will be considerably slower than its commit operation and even more slow if parallel InnoDB commits are happening in same database.